# How to use Clickhouse Token Bloomfilters with Arrays

Tags: arrays, sql-like, clickhouse, bloom-filter

How can I leverage bloomfilters on array(string) in Clickhouse.

For example, I have this data structure:

```
create table test_schema.test_table (
partition_time            DateTime64(9
,keys                     Array(String)
) ENGINE = ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree('some/path', '{replica}')
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(partition_time)
TTL toDateTime(partition_time) + toIntervalDay(1)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
```

and I build a token bloomfilter on keys

```
alter table test_schema.test_table INDEX test_bf_idx `keys` TYPE tokenbf_v1(4096, 2, 0) GRANULARITY 1;
```

When I use the condition `has(keys,'some_key')`, I can see it leveraging the bloom filter. But I could not use the bloomfilter for like queries. I have tried array filter and array join, but still it is not using bloomfilter:

```
where notEmpty(arrayFilter(x -> x LIKE '%some_key%', keys) )
```

and

```
select * from 
(select arrayJoin(keys) as val from schema.table)
where val like '%some_key%'
```

Can someone show me how I can use the token bloomfilter built on an array for LIKE statements, (i.e. use bloomfilter for like statement on an array)

Comment: If you use `LIKE` then ClickHouse has to search every string in every row (whether it's an array of strings or not). A Bloom filter is not going to be able to skip granules.

You could try an inverted index: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/invertedindexes

Comment: @RichRaposa, Clickhouse has a new tokenbf_v1 skip index which splits the strings into tokens and can be used in `LIKE` queries, see: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/optimize/skipping-indexes

Comment: https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-queries-and-syntax/skip-indexes/skip-index-bloom_filter-for-array-column/

Comment: @DennyCrane still not `LIKE` query, guess its not supported yet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe an index over arrayStringConcat ?

```sql
create table test (
    x Int64,
    k Array(String),
    INDEX test_bf_idx arrayStringConcat(k, ',') TYPE tokenbf_v1(4096, 2, 0) GRANULARITY 1
) ENGINE = MergeTree
order by x as 
select number, ['a', 'b'] k
from numbers(1e6);

select * from test
where hasToken( arrayStringConcat(k, ',') , 'xxx')
```

Comment: I have tried it out, and the bloomfilter on arrays in good for exact match and tokenized match, but not for substring match for elements in the array

In the case of exact match on array elements, I find just using plain bloomfilters and the has(array, elem) function is sufficient.

For tokenized match, I find that arrayStringConcat method together with a token_bf on the concatenated array makes "% blahblah %" matching on "prefix_blahblah_postfix". However, if the keys are not tokenized then searching for "cat" in "concatenate will not use the bloomfilter